# Custom multi-threaded Http Server isn't a thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

There is a simple multi-threaded web server I wrote in C# (the part of the code):

```
  public class MyServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private int  _dataId;
        public HttpServer(string prefix, string folder)
        {
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 1000);
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 50);
            //........
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _listener.Start();
            while (true)
             ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessRequest, _listener.GetContext());
        }


        private void ProcessRequest(object obj)
        {
           //.....
        }


}
```

If a send the requests by browser (or whatever using only one main thread) then everything is OK. But if do it by the code below, then the server usually receives the same values for different requests:

Your thought?

--**EDIT**--:

The simple question is, does using only local variables make me sure that my code is thread safe? And vise versa: if I'm using instance variables (not static, **that's _dataId in my case**), must I "look after" them to make them thread safe (for instance, by `lock` keyword)?

Comment: 1. Why don't use WCF Self-hosting service? It uses the same HttpListeners, but all this sync stuff is hidden from you. Look at WebServiceHost.

Comment: For now I have to use my custom Http Server.

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer. What does ProcessRequest do with _dataId? Without that information we cannot possibly tell if your program is thread-safe.

Comment: It writes to/reads from it. I added lock for writing but it didn't help me.

Comment: @Grienders I'm afraid that is not specific enough. Why don't you post the code? If it is long you can shorten it.

Comment: It's long and complex. Why don't you just ask my question: only yes or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to use the HttpListener in a multithreaded fashion would be through the Begin/End async pattern, [here is an example](https://gist.github.com/369432).

If your handler method is re-entrant, i.e. It does not depend on any instance state then chances are good that the code is thread-safe. Question is whether any classes, methods etc. That you use are also thread-safe.

Comment: Not sure if the async way is to be declared as canonical. The synchronous version is valid as well.

Comment: But the proposed version would gobble up all threadpool threads, wouldn't it? It seems to me fairly wasteful...

Comment: I don't know what GetContext does. I suspect is will synchonously wait for a client to request something. So this loop is well-throttled.

Answer (score -1):

You should start another thread, that will in cycle call GetContext, instead of queing the same context multiple time.

```
public void Start()
{
    _listener.Start();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartImpl);
}
public void StartImpl()
{
    while (true)
        ProcessRequest(_listener.GetContext());
}
```